# variable isn't increasing in function

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that goes up at the end of every function and the function calls on the variable. The problem is, the variable won't increase. Any advice?

```
var i;
i=0;

example function() {
<function>
 i++;
}
```

the function continually returns 1.

Comment: This is not valid sintax, you either have sintax error or function is not being called

Comment: You might want to read http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html to learn the basics about functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few problems:

- You didn't declare your function correctly - should say `function example() {` instead of `example function() {`
- The line `<function>` isn't valid javascript
- You never call your function, so it doesn't execute.

Here's a rewritten version that works:

```js
var i;
i=0;

function example() {
   i++;
}

example();   //execute the function
console.log(i);  //i should now be 1
example();   //execute the function again
console.log(i);  //i should now be 2
example();   //execute the function again
console.log(i);  //i should now be 3
```

Comment: Oh im sorry I was using that as a placeholder all of that is just example.

Comment: The actual function syntax is fine. Function x() {i++;} and the <function> was just for the code of the function.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood! Usually when writing example code I'd use a comment like `// function body goes here`

Comment: The problem is that I constantly stays at 1. is there anything you can think of?